# How to organize a chart with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT file, and I need to organize a chart where it shows features of a programming language. With each column, if the specific programming language row has the feature, it needs to print "yes". Any ideas? Still pretty new at XLST. I'm thinking if statement.

Here is what I have so far. Example, C is imperative and Procedural, so "Yes" needs to be in those columns rows.
[image]

Here is my code so far

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >    

    <xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Programming</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left">Programming</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Intended Use</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Imperaitve</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Object-Oriented</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Functional</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Procedural</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Generic</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Reflective</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Event-Driven</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Standards</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="programming/languages/language">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:variable name="intendedUseID" select="purpose/intendedUse/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/programming/purpose/intendedUse[@id=$intendedUseID]" >
           <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br  />
        </xsl:for-each></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>   <xsl:variable name="standardID" select="standards/standard/@id" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/programming/standards/standard[@id=$standardID]" >
           <xsl:value-of select="." /> <br />
        </xsl:for-each></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
    <programming>
      <languages>
        <language id="1">
          <name>C</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="2" />
            <intendedUse id="3" />
            <intendedUse id="4" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="4" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="1" />
            <standard id="2" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="2">
          <name>C++</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="2" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="3" />
            <feature id="4" />
            <feature id="5" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="2" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="3">
          <name>C#</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="5" />
            <intendedUse id="6" />
            <intendedUse id="7" />
            <intendedUse id="3" />
            <intendedUse id="8" />
            <intendedUse id="9" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="3" />
            <feature id="4" />
            <feature id="5" />
            <feature id="6" />
            <feature id="7" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="3" />
            <standard id="2" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="4">
          <name>Java</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="6" />
            <intendedUse id="7" />
            <intendedUse id="3" />
            <intendedUse id="8" />
            <intendedUse id="9" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="5" />
            <feature id="6" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="4" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="5">
          <name>JavaScript</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="7" />
            <intendedUse id="8" />
            <intendedUse id="7" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="3" />
            <feature id="6" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="3" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="6">
          <name>PHP</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="8" />
            <intendedUse id="9" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="4" />
            <feature id="6" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="5" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="7">
          <name>Python</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="3" />
            <intendedUse id="9" />
            <intendedUse id="10" />
            <intendedUse id="11" />
            <intendedUse id="12" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="3" />
            <feature id="6" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="5" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="8">
          <name>Basic</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="13" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="4" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="1" />
            <standard id="2" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="9">
          <name>ADA</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="2" />
            <intendedUse id="14" />
            <intendedUse id="15" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="4" />
            <feature id="5" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="1" />
            <standard id="2" />
            <standard id="6" />
          </standards>
        </language>
        <language id="10">
          <name>ActionScript 3.0</name>
          <purpose>
            <intendedUse id="1" />
            <intendedUse id="7" />
            <intendedUse id="9" />
          </purpose>
          <features>
            <feature id="1" />
            <feature id="2" />
            <feature id="7" />
          </features>
          <standards>
            <standard id="3" />
          </standards>
        </language>
      </languages>

      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1"> Application</intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="2"> System </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="3"> General Purpose </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="4"> Low-Level Operations </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="5"> RAD </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="6"> Business </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="7"> Client-Side </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="8"> Server-Side </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="9"> Web </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="10"> Scripting </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="11"> AI </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="12"> Scientific Computing </intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="13">Education</intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="14">Embedded</intendedUse>
        <intendedUse id="15">RealTime</intendedUse>
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1">Imperative </feature>
        <feature id="2">Object-Oriented</feature>
        <feature id="3">Functional</feature>
        <feature id="4">Procedural</feature>
        <feature id="5">Generic</feature>
        <feature id="6">Reflective</feature>
        <feature id="7">Event-Driven</feature>
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1">ANSI</standard>
        <standard id="2">ISO</standard>
        <standard id="3">ECMA</standard>
        <standard id="4">DE FACTO</standard>
        <standard id="5">NO</standard>
        <standard id="6">GOST</standard>
      </standards>
    </programming>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this question is more about producing a *cross-tab report* than "*organizing a chart*".  Anyway, I would suggest you look at it this way:

**XSLT 1.0 *(minimized to the problem at hand)***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="all-features" select="/programming/features/feature" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Language</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="$all-features">
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="programming/languages/language"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="language">
    <tr>
        <th><xsl:value-of select="name"/></th>
        <xsl:variable name="my-features" select="features/feature" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$all-features">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="@id = $my-features/@id">Yes</xsl:if>
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The (rendered) result, when applied to your input:

[image]